# Python: How to create a variable that saves locally and persists between runs

Tags: python, database, variables, persistent-storage

I want to make a password system in a program I made, but want to make it so that the first time it's run on a new computer it asks for a password but on subsequent runs it doesn't. Is there anyway to create a Boolean variable that persists between runs so that it can detect if the password was input the first time preventing future inputs of the password

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to do this.  Most people would store it in a hidden file in the user's home directory.

Comment: Persistence often use a file or database. You can store the boolean or other data you need. Consider crypting the passwords if you store them. But please show your code so we can tell you more about your problem. See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First create a file in this case 'password.txt' then save it with `False-` then code the following:

```
pass_file='password.txt'
def set_pass():
    with open(pass_file,'w') as f:
        password=input('Password please:')
        f.write(f'True - {password}')
with open(pass_file,'r') as pass:
    password_boolen=pass.read()
    if 'False' in password_boolen:
        set_pass()
    else:
        password = password_boolen[6::]
```

I hope it helped you.
Thank you
-***Lever***